# Ideal data structure for a collection of unique items in JavaScript/JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures, javascript-objects

There are (at least) two ways of storing a collection of items with unique ID's in JavaScript/JSON:

**Option A:** Object containing objects:

```
{
    "58cec042-24f1-4ccd-ae86-c34781448f01": {
        "propertyX": "...",
        "propertyY": "...",
        "propertyZ": "..."
    },
    "186564b2-bd45-40ac-8ff4-be63dab279e2": {
        // properties ...
    },
    "4fd8d376-f19f-49cd-b459-49e975f52ada": {
        // properties ...
    }
}
```

**Option B:** Array containing objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": "58cec042-24f1-4ccd-ae86-c34781448f01",
        "propertyX": "...",
        "propertyY": "...",
        "propertyZ": "..."
    },
    {
        "id": "186564b2-bd45-40ac-8ff4-be63dab279e2"
        // other properties ...
    },
    {
        "id": "4fd8d376-f19f-49cd-b459-49e975f52ada"
        // other properties ...
    }
]
```

What are the pros and cons of these options? How to decide between the two?

I can think of the following differences:

**Option A** (object containing objects):

- Retrieving a single item by ID is just a matter of `collection["id"]`.
- There are (at least) three ways to iterate over the collection:

  1. `for ... in`
  2. combining `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`
  3. `Object.entries()` (ES2017)
- The property order when iterating is not guaranteed

**Option B** (array containing objects):

- Retrieving a single item by ID requires using `.find()`
- A single item contains the ID since it is stored in the item object itself
- `Array.prototype()` contains all sorts of useful functions for working with collections

Are there any other notable differences and trade-offs?

In my case, the data structure will be used in a single page application (in the browser, client-side). Performance is important, the UI should be smooth at all times. The items will be mainly displayed in a list and filtered based on item attributes (not the ID). There might be other ways in which the collection will be used that I'm not yet aware of. The maximum amount of items being held will be around 10,000. That said, the average amount of items is more likely to be in the hundreds.

Comment: The second is good for iterating, the first for finding. Choose the one you use more often

Comment: You may also think about using maps in the first scenario if you iterate a lot on keys or if it is a big collection of data - that of course depends of your use cases.

Comment: This is also why indexes are created.  You can store the data in an array, then create an index that maps the ID to the position in the array of the matching object.

Comment: Arrays have the capability of doing a filter function for you. Would only have to come up with logic to filter properly based on criteria...example being computer specs..to filter on CPU speed or HDD space.

Comment: @JonasW. – With 'finding', you refer to finding by ID, I suppose?

Comment: @pilczuk – Maps are not available in JSON. They might be useful to consider for use in JavaScript though.

Comment: Note that your statement A.1. is not true. You cant iterate objects with `for ... of`... And yes i refer to the hashtables key.

Comment: @JonasW. – My bad, I meant `for ... in`. Fixed it.